# With Spring, @InjectMock annotated test target doesn't use mocks

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I'm trying to unit test a Spring 4.0.0 MVC application.

My controller is defined as follow:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestCtrl {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @Autowired
    private TestRessourceAssembler testRessourceAssembler;

    @Autowired
    private ResponseComposer responseComposer;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
    public HttpEntity showAll(Pageable pageable) {   
        Page<Test> patr = testService.getAll(pageable);
        return responseComposer.composePage(patr,testRessourceAssembler);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HttpEntity<TestRessource> show(@PathVariable String name) {
        Test test = testService.getOne(name);
        if(test == null){
            return new ResponseEntity("Erreur !",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return responseComposer.compose(test,testRessourceAssembler);
    }
}
```

My controller unit test is as follow:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfig.class, TestMongoConfig.class, RestConfig.class, WebMvcConfig.class})
public class TestCtrlTests{

    @InjectMocks
    TestCtrl testCtrl;

    @Mock
    TestService testService;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(testService.getOne("jexiste")).thenReturn(new com.thalesgroup.ito.c2s.mc.portail.test.domain.Test("jexiste",1990));
        when(testService.getOne("plaf")).thenReturn(null);

        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
       }

    @Test
    public void simpleGetAnswer() throws Exception{
        assertNotNull(mockMvc);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test")).andExpect(status().isOk());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test/jexiste")).andExpect(status().isOk());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test/plaf")).andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

When I'm running the test, the "normal" TestService bean is injected and used (I can see the trace in the log), not the mock.

So I read some things on the internet and replaced

```
this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
```

with

```
this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(TestCtrl.class).build();
```

But, and I knew it would happen, I've no more Spring context when doing this, so my PageableArgumentResolver and my other beans (testRessourceAssembler, responseComposer) aren't injected anymore... So they are Null and happen a NullPointerException.

My question is:

1) I'm I designing something wrong ?

2) If not, how can I inject a mock in my controller while keeping other beans from the context ?

Thanks to you !

Comment: Shouldn't MockMvc use it when I do "perform()" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm looked into your tests and this should work. Simply build your MockMvc on your controller with mocked beans. After this all mocks will be visible inside test.

> A MockMvcBuilder that accepts `@Controller` registrations thus allowing full control over the instantiation and the initialization of controllers and their dependencies similar to **plain unit tests**, and also making it possible to test **one controller** at a time.

Don't use Spring Integration test! This is simple unit testing!

### Fixed test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestCtrlTests{

    @InjectMocks
    TestCtrl testCtrl;

    @Mock
    TestService testService;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        when(testService.getOne("jexiste")).thenReturn(new com.thalesgroup.ito.c2s.mc.portail.test.domain.Test("jexiste",1990));
        when(testService.getOne("plaf")).thenReturn(null);

        this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(testCtrl).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleGetAnswer() throws Exception{
        assertNotNull(mockMvc);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test")).andExpect(status().isOk());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test/jexiste")).andExpect(status().isOk());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test/plaf")).andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nearly spent 3 hours to get the Spring testing environment mock a business logic even though my guts told me to stick to Mockito, no luck. Using mockito is good enough from what I see. Perhaps someone can enlighten us if there is any point Spring testing facilities remain superior.